# Writing char* into a basic_streambuf and assign it to a ifstream

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, io, streambuf

I have a problem, mostly because I can't really understand how to handle the situation.

I have a `char*` buffer of `X` size, it's the content of an encrypted file who's got decrypted and will be then parsed by the `ifstream` handler class **that i can't edit**.

So my idea was to create an `fstream` object in which, with `rdbuf()` assign the buffer with `sputn`.

`fstream _handle2;
_handle2.rdbuf()->sputn(_buffer, _size);
_handle2.flush();`

But of course, it's not working and buffer does not get written into the `fstream` object, do you have any idea of how to make it so?

I tried different methods but I clearly can't figure out what to do.

Comment: Why don't you use write? `handle2.write(buffer, size);`

Comment: I tried, it didn't work...if I try to read the buffer it doesn't.

Comment: How did you open your fstream? fstreams are designed to write data to a file or to read from. If it is not connected to a file, you won't get any output. But what exactly do you want to achieve in reality? Read the entire file content into some kind of data buffer? ifstream reads content of a file, you could read it e. g. byte by byte via `char c; stream >> c;`.

Comment: [Example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/) of how to read the content of an entire file into a buffer...

Comment: I'm trying to create a buffer type that can be parsed similarly to a ifstream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to create a buffer type that can be parsed similarly to a ifstream.

You might try something like this (adopted from the [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/) I provided in the comment already):

```
std::ifstream ifs("test.txt", std::ifstream::binary);
if (ifs)
{
    ifs.seekg (0, ifs.end);
    int length = ifs.tellg();
    ifs.seekg (0, ifs.beg);

    std::string buffer;
    buffer.resize(length);
    ifs.read(const_cast<char*>(buffer.data()), length);
    if (ifs)
    {
        // de-crypt the buffer here!
        // something like:
        // buffer[i] = decryptChar(buffer[i]);

        std::istringstream iss(buffer);

        // now you can use iss just the same way as ifs,
        // if the file was not encrypted...

    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "error: only " << ifs.gcount() << " bytes could be read";
    }
    ifs.close();
}
```

Edit in response to your comment:

`std::istringstream` is used to convert text into binary data, e. g. `int n; iss >> n;` would convert the string "20102012", represented by ascii sequence 0x32, 0x30, 0x31, 0x30, 0x32, 0x30, 0x31, 0x32 into the corresponding four-byte integer value of 0x0132bb7c). But if data *is* already binary, `std::istringstream` is not suitable. Then you might rather try to write your own stream class similar to this example:

```
class DecryptionStream
{
    std::unique_ptr<char> mBuffer;
    char* mEnd;
    char* mPos;
    unsigned int flags;

    unsigned int const eofbit  = 1 << 0;
    unsigned int const failbit = 1 << 1;
    // other flag bits as needed

public:
    // fail/eof bits as needed
    DecryptionStream(char const* fileName) : mPos(nullptr)
    {
        std::ifstream ifs(fileName, std::ifstream::binary);
        if (ifs)
        {
            ifs.seekg (0, ifs.end);
            int length = ifs.tellg();
            ifs.seekg (0, ifs.beg);

            mBuffer.reset(new char[length]);
            ifs.read(mBuffer.get(), length);
            if (ifs)
            {
                // de-crypt the buffer here!
                // something like:
                // buffer[i] = decryptChar(buffer[i]);
                mPos = mBuffer.get();
                mEnd = mBuffer.get() + length;
            }
            else
            {
                flags |= failbit;
            }
            ifs.close();
        }
    }

    template<typename T>
    DecryptionStream& operator >>(T& t)
    {
        // fail, if any fail bit set already
        size_t avail = mPos - mEnd;
        if (avail < sizeof(t))
        {
            flags |= eofbit | failbit;
        }
        else
        {
            if(avail == sizeof(t))
            {
                flags |= eofbit;
            }
            memcpy(&t, mPos, sizeof(t));
            mPos += sizeof(t);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    operator bool()
    {
        return flags == 0;
    }
};
```

You could even use this class with complex data types - then make sure, though, that you control byte alignment of these appropriately, otherwise you might fail badly!

Comment: Wasn't exactly what I was asking for, but with part of this code I edited a bit I've been able to do what I did; thanks.

Comment: Now, thing is I'm not handlng strings but a raw binary buffer, I added the ios::binary flag but I'm afraid it's not correctly reading part of the buffer.

Comment: Binary content? `std::istringstream` then is not suitable. Extended my anser appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`boost::iostreams::array_source`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/array.html).

It allows you to treat an array as a `std::istream`. The advantage over `std::istringstream` is that the array will not be copied into the stream, which reduces memory usage and increases performance. The `array_source` will just store a pointer to the existing buffer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/array.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
namespace io = boost::iostreams;

int main()
{   
    // Create an array and wrap a stream interface around it.
    const char buffer[] = "hello stackoverflow";
    io::stream< io::array_source > strm( buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1 );  //-1 to strip '\0'

    // Use the stream like a standard istream.
    std::string s;
    while( strm >> s )
        std::cout << s << "\n";
}
```

[Live Demo on Coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8098045d50e46c20)